# After creating a virtual machine in a vmware 15.5 workstation and running it to find that the system being used was not found

Tags: vmware

I have a problem with the Vmware program after creating a virtual machine in vmware workstation 15.5 and running it shows that the operating system was not found, how to fix it, please write it step by step. I am a total amateur of this program so if you can attach some video photo how to do it thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

VMware Machines are stored in folders on your computer. One folder for each machine normally. The best thing is to open Windows Explorer, and look for your Machine folder. Look in Documents if you used the Default folder location.

When you have found the folder, there should be a .VMX file (settings file). Try to open this with VMware (not Explorer).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine (VM) is a virtual form of physical computer hardware.  If you bought physical computer parts and assembled your own physical machine, it also would have no operating system.

You need to explicitly install an operating system in the virtual machine, just like you'd need to do on a physical machine.

When you create the virtual machine, one of the steps of the "New Virtual Machine wizard" asks you to how you want to install the guest operating system.  From there you should be able to specify an `.iso` image or a physical installation disc.